# Question regarding using conda-pack with different Linux distributions

Tags: python, conda, python-packaging

Under the Caveats section of the home page (https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/#caveats) it says that "the os type where the environment was built must match the os type of the target".
Does this mean that a conda environment packed in Ubuntu won't work in Amazon Linux?

I wanted to confirm this since (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/moving-conda-environments) seems to suggest so. So far I haven't been able to show this conclusively when I ship about environments created in Ubuntu to Amazon Linux.

Comment: I am curious about this question as well, working on porting pip/conda packs to my company cluster that uses Red Hat. Hope to let you know when result turns out.